# ffmpeg - how to set max frame rate

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to convert video and I would like to set max framerate.
For example, I have a video which is 46 framerate, but I want to set this to 40.

This is my code below:

```
var cmd = ffmpeg()
      .input(data.img_path)
      .format('mp4')
      .videoCodec('libx264')
      .audioBitrate('192k')
      .audioChannels(2)
      .outputOptions('-movflags', 'frag_keyframe')
      ....
```

Answer (score 1):

`-fpsmax[:stream_specifier] fps (output,per-stream)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.outputOptions('-vf', 'fps=40')`

Comment: @user19283043 Depending to your content, you may also try [minterpolate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#minterpolate) or [framerate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#framerate) filters.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15276593)

Comment: @AdamWolski - in what universe it doesn't provide an answer? The presented code should precisely do what the OP asked. Sure, it can be done in several other ways, this is just one of them.